# How to exit().transition rects under a col in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart that shows values either for month or year.

It is composed of a series of columns (1 or 12), and rects within each column (9 individual values).

You can see it here: (Note - this is a valid web page, currently running on AWS.)

```
http://54.245.225.47/stackedbar_ex_good
```

When I go from months to year view, I want to move all the positions to the yearly value, then fade them out as the year values `.enter()`.

The problem is that the rects (where I would normally do the `.exit().transition().attr("y", new_val)` never gets called since the column gets deleted (`.exit()`). And when I tried referencing the child `.rects` from the `svg.selectAll(".col").exit().transition()`, they seemed to disappear all at once. I'm guessing this is the wrong way.

Sorry this is so confusing!  I'm sure this sort of thing is answered elsewhere, but I don't even know the language to describe it properly (and hence search for it). Any tips / pointers would be appreciated.

(There is a lot of code - I don't know how to simplify in order to even post it.)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, kinda hard to understand the problem... As I understand it, you want to animate the exiting rects to some position before they're removed from the SVG. But your problem is that the rects' parents –– `col` in your code –– are removed immediately, and so the nested rects never have a chance to animate. Right?

If so, one way around it is to delay the removal of the exiting `col`'s in order to give the `rects` animation time to play. So, rather than doing:

```
col.exit().remove()
```

apply a the delay like so:

```
col.exit().transition().delay(2000).remove()
```

There's no actual, visible transition here; it's just a way to delay the call to `remove()`.

Comment: Yes - you understood my problem exactly. I had tried what you mentioned, but must have done something wrong. But this got me back on the track, and i think it is a combination of the delay you mention and "subtransitions" (see here). I'm not done (and will post when complete), but I'm pretty sure it is:

Comment: `col.exit().transition().selectAll("rect").<do rect stuff here> `

`col.exit().transition().delay(2500).remove() <-- finally remove the cols.`

btw - subtransitions link: [link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-transition)

Comment: @RossR comment in particular really helpeed me.
I was able to generalize this to my case of transitioning a circle element within a g element before removing the whole g element.  This seems to be the pattern in general for transitioning a child element before removing it all-together via its ancestor removal.